# How do I export to mtl and obj files with textures for use with three.js?

Tags: texturing, export, three.js

I have a 15MB blend file from here:
http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/72717

a quote on the page from the uploader "The textures (included the background), were taken by me and can be used freely."

how do i get this wood texture? (i would like all the included textures)
I am familiar with an .mtl file and seperate image files to be mapped to the object/model.  Can I get blender to ouput this?  How?

Also, I have tried triangulating and checked all the boxes that should be checked during export, but all I ever get is a severly messed up model when viewed with three.js.  About half the faces are missing and no textures.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding you correctly, what you're asking is: 1) How do I export to three.js without mesh errors and 2) How do I export the model to three.js WITH the included image textures. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712857/how-to-load-textures-from-objmtl-files-in-three-js-in-the-year-2013

Comment: Not a duplicate of 17712857.  That question is about loading a texture into three.js. I am trying to get them out of blender.